# Basic data type Accuracy

Tags: java, android

I find a problem when i use the long to save a month milliseconds. but i print negative number.so i make a test

code below:

```
LogUtils.d(TAG, "long max time:"+Long.MAX_VALUE);
LogUtils.d(TAG, "long min time:"+Long.MIN_VALUE);
LogUtils.d(TAG, "a month time:"+1000*60*60*24*30);
LogUtils.d(TAG, "a year time:"+1000*60*60*24*365);
```

print:

```
long max time:9223372036854775807
long min time:-9223372036854775808
a month time:-1702967296
a year time:1471228928
```

and why a month time print:-1702967296

Comment: System.out.println("a month time:"+1000L*60*60*24*30);

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expression `1000*60*60*24*30`, each term is an `int`, so the results of each multiplication will also be `int`.  You're getting integer overflow here, which causes the result to be negative.  Even after you've converted it to `long`, it's still the same negative number.

You need to write `1000L*60*60*24*30` instead, which causes the result of each multiplication to be `long`.  That is, `1000L` is a `long` whose value is 1000, and whenever you multiply a `long` by an `int`, the result is still `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: the first two lines result in **long** being printed.

The final two ones are *ints*. Which are running over.

By default whole number literals are interpreted as intended, not long.

Go for

```
1000L * 60 *...
```

Instead. This will cause the compiler to computer the whole expression as long.